# Rolling regression with expanding window

Tags: r, regression, rolling-computation

I am new to R and I am trying to run rolling regressions with an expanding window (that is for each date t use data up to t), with two independent variables in a data frame grouped by a categorical column.

For example, in the data frame below, I would like to extract coefficients of lm(return ~ regress1 + regress 2) grouped by category K using all rows until the row of interest. Thus for row 2, data set for regression will be rows 1:2, for row 3 will be rows 1:3, for row 4 will be just row 4 as it is the first row with categorical variable K = B.

```
myinput <- data.frame(K = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), 
                      date = c(1:3) , return = rnorm(9), regress1 = rnorm(9), regress2 = rnorm(9))
```

I found a very useful thread on this topic here: [Rolling regression with expanding window in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461067/rolling-regression-with-expanding-window-in-r), but I am having a difficult time applying it to my data set.

If anyone could help me understand how I need to adapt the approach they used it'd be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `myinput` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, define a function `reg` to perform the regression.    Then use `rollapplyr` with a `width` argument equal to `date` making use of the fact that `date` is 1, 2, 3, etc. within group and so equals the number of rows to regress over. Finally `cbind` the result back to the original data frame.

```
library(zoo)

reg <- function(x) coef(lm(as.data.frame(x)))

r <- rollapplyr(zoo(myinput[3:5]), myinput$date, reg, by.column=FALSE, coredata=FALSE)
cbind(myinput, coef = coredata(r))
```

giving:

```
  K date      return   regress1   regress2 coef.(Intercept) coef.regress1 coef.regress2
1 A    1 -0.56047565 -0.4456620  0.7013559      -0.56047565            NA            NA
2 A    2 -0.23017749  1.2240818 -0.4727914      -0.47231761     0.1978137            NA
3 A    3  1.55870831  0.3598138 -1.0678237       0.15985654    -0.9479906    -1.6294374
4 B    1  0.07050839  0.4007715 -0.2179749       0.07050839            NA            NA
5 B    2  0.12928774  0.1106827 -1.0260044       0.15171486    -0.2026254            NA
6 B    3  1.71506499 -0.5558411 -0.7288912       1.05050327    -2.0789081     0.6735997
7 C    1  0.46091621  1.7869131 -0.6250393       0.46091621            NA            NA
8 C    2 -1.26506123  0.4978505 -1.6866933      -1.93165311     1.3389399            NA
9 C    3 -0.68685285 -1.9666172  0.8377870      -0.14625482     0.6376389     0.8515213
```

### Note

`set.seed` must be used prior to using random data in order to make the result reproducible.  We used this:

```
set.seed(123)
myinput <- data.frame(K = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), 
  date = 1:3, return = rnorm(9), regress1 = rnorm(9), regress2 = rnorm(9))
```

Comment: Thank you @G. Grothendieck. This looks great. However, when I apply rollapply I get the following error: Error in Math.POSIXt(length.out) : 
  'ceiling' not defined for "POSIXt" objects.

Maybe I should add that the dates I use aren't actually in a 1, 2, 3 format but 92 quarters from 1997-03-31 to 1997-06-30, 1997-09-30 etc. for every category (probably should've included this in the question, sorry for that). Could this be why I get the error?

Comment: If every group has the same number of rows, k (where k = nrow(myinput) / nlevels(myinput$K) which is 3 in the question) then the date column must be 1:k. within group to use the code verbatim. If not, then myinput$w <- 1:k can be used to create a column w that can be used in place of date. as the value of the width= argument in rollapplyr. If the groups are of different size (or even if not) we can use w <- with(myinput, ave(seq_along(K), K, FUN = seq_along))